Can Civimail be used (send or receive) with the Civimobile app?
Will sometimes need to access CiviCrm site (on Wordpress) remotely and the CiviMobile app looks good. Email is not mentioned in the app description so wondering if the functions of CiviMail can be accessed through CiviMobile.

Since it is not mentioned at https://civimobile.org/features/
and nor on the roadmap https://civimobile.org/civimobile-roadmap/ i expect the answer is no.
YOu may be best to reach out to the developers directly
